# How do I properly use or in Python?

Tags: python

I think I'm misusing `or`, because this will just loop even when the input is either beer wine or strong. How can I make this run as intended?

```
req1 = ""
while req1 != "beer" or "wine" or "strong":
     req1=input("wat wil je drinken? ")
```

Comment: `while req1 not in ('beer', 'wine', 'strong'):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do:

```
req1 = ""
while req1 != "beer" or req1 != "wine" or req1 != "strong":
     req1=input("wat wil je drinken? ")
```

Comment: `or` should be `and`

Comment: This is endlessly duplicated, we don't need yet another answer.

Comment: I don't know what happend to this post but thanks for the answer